# how to insert into a table from another table and also using a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-insert

I tried below but I got violation of Primary key.

```
insert into a_c ([a_id],  [C_id], [ac_id])
  select  t2.A,t2.C , dbo.getac_id() from  table_2 t2
```

I also tried using cursor it did not work.

```
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR select  t2.A,t2.C from  table_2 t2

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @cid,@aid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
--insert into table row by row
insert into ing_spe.[dbo].ACTIVITY_CONTACT ( [A_ID],[C_ID], [A_C_ID]) SELECT @aid,@cid, dbo.getac_id() 
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @cid,@aid

END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
GO
```

---

Note:
**dbo.getac_id()** returns single value. The logic inside it performs some calculation and fetches the max value of ac_id in the table a_c  returns the unique value.
Column "**ac_id**" is a Primary Key.

** desired output**

```
[a_id],    [C_id],   [ac_id]
a1         c1          1011
a1         c2          1012
a2         c1          1013
a3         c4          1014
```

Comment: There's no need for a `CURSOR` here at all. You can certainly achieve this in a dataset method. If the first method said that you had a primary key violation sounds like you were trying to `INSERT` rows that already exists in table `a_c`; perhaps you need a `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: the first method is trying to insert in this way:[a_id],    [C_id],   [ac_id]
a1         c1          1011
a1         c2          1011
a2         c1          1011
a3         c4          1011         Hence I am getting primary key violation.

Comment: The syntax does not work.

Comment: I will not be able to hard code it. I have to use a variable, but identity function will not allow us to add the variable as its parameter.

Comment: could you provide your table definition where you're trying to insert ? which column is your PK ?

Comment: You said dbo.getac_id() "fetches the max value of ac_id". If that's correct, you should be adding 1 to it before inserting the new record. If you want the first query to work, you could add a row_number() to it instead. Also, you're sooner or later likely to have problems with this kind of ID allocation, some other user will jump in and use an ID before you can, make sure you have proper error handling to handle this.

Comment: Definitely need more code to review what you are attempting.  As a blind guess, consider adding OPTION (FORCE ORDER).  And is what you are trying to do possible using Row_Number() - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DancingFool. Thank you like you said row_number worked fine.

Comment: @Stan. Thank you like you said Row_Number worked fine.